# Unable to find solution (divergence, multivariable calculus)

Tags: calculus

Problem:
What functions $f(x)$ satisfy the condition

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf u = 0$$

When
$$\mathbf u = f(x) \nabla(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$$

My solution so far (but it's wrong somewhere):

$\nabla(x^2+y^2+z^2) = (2x, 2y, 2z) = 2(x, y, z)$

$\mathbf u = 2(xf(x), yf(x), zf(x))$

$\nabla \cdot \mathbf u = \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial y}  + \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial z}$

$\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x} = 2f(x) + 2xf'(x)$

$\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial y} = 2f(x)$

$\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial z} = 2f(x)$

$\nabla \cdot \mathbf u = 0$ gives $6f(x) + 2xf'(x) = 0$

$f(x) = - \frac x3 f'(x)$

(Thanks Ted for correcting me but I still do something terribly wrong)

Supposedly it should be $f(x) = C/x^3$ where $C$ is an arbitrarily chosen constant but I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong :-(

**Update**
Solved the separable differential equation which made it pretty obvious.

$\frac{y'}{y} = -\frac{3}{x}$ (separable differential equation $g(y)y'=h(x)$)

integrate both sides

$\int{\frac{y'}{y}dy} = \int{-\frac{3}{x}dx}$

$ln(y) = -3 \cdot ln(x)+C1$

$e^{ln(y)} = e^{-3 \cdot ln(x)+C1}$

$y = x^{-3} \cdot e^{C1}$

$y = \frac{e^{C1}}{x^{3}} = \frac{C2}{x^{3}}$

Thank you all for the hints!
It helped me understand my shortcomings :-)

Comment: You need a vector *field* to talk about divergence (and your definition of div needs to be repaired appropriately). And, while you're fixing things, when you write $f(x)$ you mean that the function does not depend on $y$ and $z$?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. f(x) does not depend on y or z. I will repair my statement... I think I forgot a nabla operator around the (x^2+y^2+z^2)

Comment: You need to work on learning basic MathJax so that we can read your posts :) So, with the correction, we have $\text{div}\mathbf u = 2\big(f(x)+x'f(x)+f(x)+f(x)\big) = 0$ if and only if $3f(x)+xf'(x)=0$, which is indeed what you had. Now you have to separate variables to solve $x\dfrac{dy}{dx}  = 3y$.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is stopping before you get to the answer. Everything you've done so far is okay. Now solve your differential equation for $f$.